# I need to access the current character and the characters that follow, by their index, while looping through a string

Tags: python, word-count

So I was just messing around, trying to loop through every single character in a string and picking out patterns forming particular words, instead of using inbuilt functions or split(). I was able to do this in Javascript, but don't understand how to do the same in python. Here is my simple JS program for counting the word 'this' or 'This':

```js
let str1 = "This is a sample string and this is a sample string too. That and this are also sample strings, just like this one";
let count = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++){
    if((str1[i] == 't' || str1[i] == 'T') && str1[i+1] == 'h' && str1[i+2] == 'i' && str1[i+3] == 's'){
        count += 1;
    }
}

console.log(count); // => 4
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 trying to do this in Python

Comment: @mkrieger1 , don't understand what would the python syntax be for accessing the characters that follow the current character, inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

The two language is surprisingly similar,

```
str1 = "This is a sample string and this is a sample string too. That and this are also sample strings, just like this one";
count = 0
for i in range(len(str1)):
    if str1[i].lower() == 't' and str1[i+1] == 'h' and str1[i+2] == 'i' and str1[i+3] == 's':
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: Right, using range did not cross my mind. Thank you so much man  :)

Comment: FYI, print(str1.lower().count('this')) will do the same thing.

Comment: Great, thanks man. Just wanted to avoid using any inbuilt methods, even split()